# Editing carrier.plist in Filza?

Tags: ios, iphone, settings, jailbreak, carrier

I just downloaded FilzaEscaped, and was scrolling through it and found the carrier.plist for my carrier. If I were to change something (carrier name for example), would it mess up my phone? And if it did, is there a way to backup the original settings and restore if something goes wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can freely edit it however tampering with it will make the signature for the file invalid so it might just end up doing nothing at all and revert to its original state. if you want to change the carrier name the values are located  in the key `StatusBarImages`
See here for more info https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Carrier.plist

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that was the only thing I could changed. If I jailbreak my phone, and the commcenter is patched, would that allow me to change the other settings without having to deal with the signature for the file messing things up?

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the.plist file if you'd like... however after your next re-jailbreak (perhaps your phone ran out of charge or you restarted your device) the files will revert. The only relevant settings are in the APN section. I would suggest installing carrier update remover, and/or using untetherme 8+ to change these settings.